# How to get Python unittest skipped result as Failed

Tags: python, python-unittest

When running `test_B` , how do I check and skip my `test_B` when my `TextTestRunner pass_result` variable keep getting pass when my `test_A` is actually being skipped? Isit possible to set `TextTestRunner` to show skipped result as failed instead of passing result?

```
import unittest

class TestStringResult(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_A(self):
        missing = 1;
        if (missing):
            raise unittest.SkipTest('Required information is missing') 

    def test_B(self):
        pass_result =  unittest.TextTestRunner().run(TestStringResult('test_A')) 
        if not (pass_result):
            raise unittest.SkipTest('test_A has been skipped')
        print('test_A runs smoothly')
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This is the output I am currently getting. :

> ```
> test_B(__main__.TestStringResult) ... s
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------  
> Ran 1 test in 0.074s
>
> OK (skipped=1) 
> test_A runs smoothly ok
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> Ran 1 test in 0.089s
>
> OK
> ```

Comment: Well, yes; an *exception is being raised*, so there is no value to assign to `pass_result`. Do you understand how to handle exceptions, *in general*? If so, I don't understand why there is a question; if not, that is what you need to either look up or find a duplicate for.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I tried printing the value for pass_result. it is showing 
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=1 errors=0 failures=0>.

Comment: Check for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70170057/how-to-get-failed-succes-error-test-cases-names-from-the-unittest-runner-text).

Comment: Thank you @MrBeanBremen .I was able to get the result I wanted. :)